# Is it possible to call a command/script on mouse hover over a window?

Tags: mate-desktop

My system is Linux Mint MATE 18.3 and additionally I am using compiz.

Is it possible to attach a command or script to something like a window hover event?

If yes, the second part of the question is, if there is a "unhover" or "leaving" window event as well...

---

Optional background:

I just discovered how to make windows transparent here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1109425/40569

This is really cool and I already bound a hotkey for that. Now even more cool would be to let a window become opaque again, as long as it is hovered.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But not from the shell. With the X11 C library, you should `XSelectInput(dpy, w, EnterWindowMask|LeaveWindowMask)` and then look for `Enter-` and `LeaveNotify` events. Go get the [x11 lib manual](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html). Other higher level interfaces like gtk or qt offer their own ways to achieve that, and may have python or perl bindings, etc.

Comment: Thank you for these informations, I will check this